# Merging two csv files - giving one extra column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

while merging two csv files having

1. 1773 rows * 3 columns and
2. 61 rows and 3 columns

having column attributes as 'Question', Answer and Class

getting one extra column

used techniques such as merge, concat and append also.. but still the same

```py
# Importing Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Mounting google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

# Reading csv file
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/BankFAQs.csv')
# removing duplicate items
df.duplicated().sum() - #removed 277 duplicates
df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)

# removed duplicate items storing in dffinal
df.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/dffinal.csv', index=False)

# try to merge 2 csv's
df1 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/dffinal.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/TobeMerged.csv', encoding='windows-1252')

# using various methods to merge
dfmaster = pd.concat([df1, df2])
dfmaster1 = df1.append(df2, [['Q', 'A', 'C']])
```

Comment: no error however I am getting one extra column

Comment: what are the columns you end up with?

Comment: Copy paste a sample of both CSV with the headers (no screenshot) as at this point it is impossible to tell what is going on because we miss [mcve]. That will definitely help to reproduce the issue and get a solution. Seems data related bug anyway. Cheers.